# Automatic Field Order Rearrangement in D

Tags: class, struct, alignment, field, d

I just saw the following at http://dlang.org/pretod.html#pragmapack quote:

For D **classes**, there is no need to adjust the **alignment** (in fact, the compiler is **free to rearrange the data fields to get the optimum layout**, much as the compiler will rearrange local variables on the stack frame). For D structs that get mapped onto externally defined data structures, there is a need, and it is handled with:

```
struct Foo
{
    align (4):  // use 4 byte alignment
    ...
}
```

Does this mean that structs fields are not rearranged as are class fields mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although I don't think current implementations rearrange class fields anyway.